# How to create "dual" Spine.js application?

Tags: coffeescript, javascriptmvc, spine.js

I would like to have two-panel filemanager like mc or total commander. Do I have to create two different controllers with same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can just use two instances of the same controller. Something like:

```
new App.FileManager({el: $('#panel_left')});
new App.FileManager({el: $('#panel_right')});
```

Obviously, it's just a general idea.